# How to automount a share on every user on the computer?

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, automount, cifs

I want to automount a share from a Ubuntu file-server on my Ubuntu client.
I managed to actually mount it with with the following line in `/etc/fstab` :

```
//192.168.1.64/myProj3kt/myProj3kt /home/administrator/myProjekt cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

I tried to repeat the command in `/etc/fstab` with different users, but the following error popped up:

```
Unable to access "sharename" mount: according to mtab is already mounted on xxxx/xxxx
```

I read on this forum about a `credentials-file` but I never used/made one. Can someone help me?